# Can't build on Xcode using 'capacitor js' commands

Tags: ios, xcode, capacitor

I'm practicing capacitor js, and was able successfully to package the (html, css & js) files and build them on 'android studio' according to the commands on '`https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android`'.

Yet when i powered up macOS version 10.14 on VMware and tried to do the same steps '`https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios`' to build on Xcode, the following warnings and errors occured...

[Bugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFEzs.jpg)

I traced the path written in the error and couldn't find neither file nor folder named Pods....

[The App folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai7Tt.jpg)

I'm using XCode version 11.3 and did install 'Node.js & Xcode command line tools' as mentioned as "capacitor js requirements" on the documentation, also installed CocoaPods.

It's my first time using macOS so I might have missed some additional steps that needed to be done.

Would be very thankful if anyone could guide me through that bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've openend the .xcodeproj file. Don't do that, use the .xcworkspace exclusively. Also, if you don't have a Pods folder, you probably forgot to run `pod install`

Comment: Spectacular !
Got some warnings but It actually was built and works just fine now :D
Really appreciate it, thank you.... i'll add the steps that i used as an answer to the question.

Comment: If the answer helped solve your problem, please click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: I did, but i have less than 15 reputation so it won't be submitted

Comment: I think you're confusing this with the upvote (up arrow) button, the checkmark should be accessible for all question askers.

Comment: Oh! nice to know that, checked it... & thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Gereon** the step that was missing is to use the command `pod install` on the 'App' folder that has the 'Podfile.txt', it will extract some extra files including the required Pods folder.

[App Folder After Using `pod install`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIzLG.jpg)

If after building you faced the following error...

> failed to initiate service connection to simulator

Just clean the build folder and run again.

To clean the build folder you can use the shortcut Command+Option+Shift+K or Menu Bar → Product → Hold Option Key → Clean build Folder.